# How can I pull objects from parse and display them in a list without their ID in android?

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-listview, parse-platform

For example if I had an object that was a person's information such as weight, height, etc, how would I be able to display a list of people without having to call each person's ID individually? I know people have suggested queries before, but the parse docs for queries are in JS and android is in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty docs on android: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

What you want is ParseQueryAdapter: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-queryadapter

Comment: The parsequeryadapter is just what I needed! Thank you so much.